# Оператор return

Tags: python, алгоритм

Я начинающий программист и не совсем понимаю работу оператора `return`.
Подскажите, в 3 строке кода `retrun` возвращает значение в функцию `square` или функцию в `sqrt_r`?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
def sqrt_r(number, precision_factor=0.0001):
    def square(n):
        return n * n
    def good_enough(guess, number):
        return abs(square(guess) - number) < precision_factor
    def improve(guess, number):
        return ((number/guess) + guess) / 2
    def sqrt_iter(guess, number):
        return guess \
               if good_enough(guess, number) \
               else sqrt_iter(improve(guess, number), number)
    return sqrt_iter(1.0, number)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: return n*n Возращяет квадрат значения переданного параметра

Comment: Исправил код, можете смотреть

Comment: А где показывают такую порнографию?

Answer (score 5):

при объявлении функции с помощью ключевого слова def происходит присвоение объекта-функции к имени, ни какого вызова сразу же не происходит, после объявления функцию можно уже вызывать в необходимом месте, возвращение результата происходит в точке вызова функции.

логику происходящего можно понять по выводу кода ниже:

```
def foo():
    print('до обьявления sub_foo')

    def sub_foo():
        print('исполнение sub_foo')
        return True

    print('после обьявления sub_foo')

    flag = sub_foo()
    print(flag)


foo()
```

**вывод:**

```
#до обьявления sub_foo
#после обьявления sub_foo
#исполнение sub_foo
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте рассмотрим всё это на примерах.

Пример 1

```
def function():
    print("Выполнение function")

    def print_number(number):
        print(number)
    
    return print_number
```

Функция возвращает объект функции. Теперь мы можем сделать так

```
x = function()
print("function выполнена")
x(8)
```

Код выведет

```
Выполнение function
function выполнена
8
```

Или так

```
function()(9)
print("всё выполнено")
```

Это код выведет

```
Выполнение function
9
всё выполнено
```

Теперь рассмотрим другой пример

Пример 2

```
def function_2(x):
    print("Выполнение function_2")

    def print_number(number):
        print(number)
    
    return print_number(2)
```

Функция возвращает уже не объект функции, а то что вернёт функция
Выполним код, с использованием этой функции

```
x = function_2(8)
print("function_2 выполнена")
print(x)
```

Этот код выведет

```
Выполнение function_2
2
function_2 выполнена
None
```

*Надеюсь понятно*

Answer (score 0):

`return n * n` это результат выполнения функции `square` . Он будет возвращен в то место откуда была вызвана эта функция. Советую посмотреть по шагам как будет работать ваш [код](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit). Скопируйте код и вызовите `sqrt_r(2)`.